# Destructor calls out-numbering constructor calls

Tags: c++

I was trying to understand how exactly the constructor and destructor works, but kinda stumbled on this code and was finding it difficult to understand why the destructor is called 4 times but not the constructor. Please help me understand the flow of this pgm.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#define PRINT(N) cout << #N <<endl;

class Player
{
private:
    int Health;
    int Wealth;
public:
    Player(int x = 0, int y = 0): Health(x), Wealth(y) //initializing with constructor
    {
        cout << " Constructor is called " << endl;
    }

    void sethealth(int num)
    {
        Health = num;
    }

    void setwealth(int num)
    {
        Wealth = num;
    }

    int gethealth()
    {
        return Health;
    }

    int getwealth()
    {
        return Wealth;
    }
    ~Player()  // Destructor being called
    {
        cout << " Destructor is called " << endl;
    }
};

void _display(Player _obj)
{
    cout << "Players health is  " << _obj.gethealth() << endl;
    cout << "Player's wealth is  " << _obj.getwealth() << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Player player1, player2;
    int num1 = 100, num2 = 150, num3 = 10, num4 = 20;

    player1.sethealth(num1);
    player2.sethealth(num2);

    player1.setwealth(num3);
    player2.setwealth(num4);

    PRINT(player1);
    _display(player1);
    PRINT(player2);
    _display(player2);


    return 0;
}
```

Output is as shown below: as you see, the constructor is called twice as expected, but why would destructor being called in between and again after the exit of main()

```
Constructor is called
Constructor is called
player1
Players health is  100
Player's wealth is  10
Destructor is called
player2
Players health is  150
Player's wealth is  20
Destructor is called

Destructor is called
Destructor is called
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Every time you call the display function, you make a copy of its argument. But your copy constructor doesn't print a nice message out.

Comment: A class can have many constructors, but only one destructor.

Answer (score 2):

It calls the copy constructor when you call the following function:

```
void _display(Player _obj){
 cout << "Players health is  " <<_obj.gethealth() <<endl;
 cout <<"Player's wealth is  "<< _obj.getwealth() <<endl;
}
```

You can define your own copy-constructor to see the effect.

```
Player(const Player& temp):Health(temp.Health), Wealth(temp.Wealth) {
    std::cout << "Copy constructor was called." << std::endl;
}
```

Just for an advice: If you want to avoid the extra copies and your sole purpose is to read the data from object, you should pass it by reference:

```
void _display(const Player &_obj){
 cout << "Players health is  " <<_obj.gethealth() <<endl;
 cout <<"Player's wealth is  "<< _obj.getwealth() <<endl;
}
```

Comment: cool... so, is this the std format to have a look at explicit copy constructor...because why would one use "const" data type and a "temp" reference to "Player class"... what exactly is going on, in this small bit of code..?

Comment: Yes, please take a look at what a [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) is and what it does. In your case you don't really need a copy constructor because there aren't any dynamically allocated member variables in your class.

Answer (score 1):

Your `display` function takes the argument by value, which means that a copy is created - and that copy needs to get destructed as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the copy constructor:

```
class Player{
// ...
public:
  Player(const Player& other):Health(other.Health), Wealth(other.Wealth) {
    cout << "copy ctor" << endl;
  }
// ...
};
```

Comment: @anil150886 My code was missing member variables initialization, refresh and check it out